# Is it possible for a firewall to block wss: (websocket over https) while allowing https pass through?

Tags: websocket

I'm implementing a mobile app which uses a WSS WebSocket over HTTPS to talk to the cloud service.

I'm wondering, do I need to implement HTTPS Long Polling in case the WebSocket is blocked by a firewall? My understanding is that WebSocket is on top of HTTP. If HTTPS is allowed, there is no way to block WebSocket over HTTPS since the firewall doesn't know what data is exchanged.

Can anybody please confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket doesn't technically run over HTTP/S.  It is a separate protocol.  It just happens to use an HTTP/S-compatible handshake, but then quickly switches away from HTTP/S.

But yes, the WebSocket handshake is modeled after HTTP/S specifically for interoperability with existing HTTP/S servers and firewalls.  So, if HTTP/S can pass through the firewall, so can WS/S.